# Why do I get Err 403 (Forbidden) when I use Chrome/FF with https but when I connect via CarotDAV it works fine

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, http-status-code-403, webdav

Can anyone here explain the problem, Why do I get `Error 403 (Forbidden)` but when I connect to a https WEBDAV I can get the Directory Listing. I use WebDAV Server on Ubuntu 18.4 with valid Certificate and port 4433.

When I use CarotDAV I can see all files in the directory and works fine. But with Chrome or FF or when I use the IPWorks WebDAv compononet (separate question: [Q&A for WebDAV Comp from nsoftware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430436/i-get-an-error-403-with-my-delphi-webdav-program-nor-carotdav-client-works-fine/63486103#63486103) ) in Delphi 10.4 I get Error 403 from Server. Is there a option to set in the https.conf in apache to see the directory listing also in Chrome/FF ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I could see: with this  options it works fine also with Chrome/FF

```
    Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

   <Directory "/var/www/icons">
      Options Indexes MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
```